# How to extract the value of a select within select using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code here:

```
if(isset($_POST['possible_new_dd'])){
    $dd = $_POST['possible_new_dd'];
    $id = $_POST['possible_new_dd_id'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(COILS),MACHINE, (SELECT COILS FROM ORDERS WHERE ID='$id') FROM ORDERS WHERE MACHINE=(SELECT MACHINE FROM ORDERS WHERE ID='$id') AND C_DD='$dd';");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    $json->coils = $row['SUM(COILS)'];
    $json->machine = $row['MACHINE'];
    $json->new_coil = $row['?THE SELECT QUERY?'];
    $j = json_encode($json);
    echo$j;
}
```

In the json string I can read machine and coils, but I cant find a way to read this bit **(SELECT COILS FROM ORDERS WHERE ID='$id')**.

How do I get this value to be stored into a json string?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way  is use an alias eg  MY_COL

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(COILS),MACHINE, 
    (SELECT COILS FROM ORDERS WHERE ID='$id')  AS MY_COL 
FROM ORDERS 
WHERE MACHINE=(SELECT MACHINE FROM ORDERS WHERE ID='$id') AND C_DD='$dd';");
```

and so you can access easly to the result

```
  $json->my_col= $row['MY_COL'];
```

*but you should not use php var inside  in SQL. (you are at risk for sql injection )  To avoid this you should use binding param so take a look at this feature and refactor your code*

Comment: Thank you for the heads up I will look into it :)

Comment: I have used variable inside SQL for too many pages now, I will see what I can do about that.

Comment: @Luke  . is important  that you use a sanitized  way for use value in sql so take a real look at binding param